# Does Shani Sade Sati really affects?

Tags: belief, astrology, shani

Does Shani's Sade Sati really affects our luck. I have heard from many people that Shani's Sade Sati have ill effects on our luck and career. What is it and What's its origin? Also what are the remedies for it to lower its affect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Shani dev ( शनि देव )** is one of the Navagrah (नवग्रह) **from astrology point of Hinduism Or Jyotish Shastra (ज्योतिष शास्त्र).**  He is Planet Saturn.and is also known  as Shanishwra (शनैश्चर).

See More On SADE-SATI [Here](http://www.vedicscholar.com/sadesatti.php)

The  mantras for pleasing Shani Bhagvan is from the famous **NAVAGRAHA STOTRAM  (नवग्रह स्तोत्र)** composed by **Shri Veda Vyasa (वेद व्यास).**

> **नीलांजन समाभासम रवि पुत्रम यमाग्रजं ।**
>
> **छाया मार्तान्ड समभुतम तं नमामि शनिश्चरम ।।**
>
> NILANJANA SAMABHASAM RAVI PUTRAM YAMAGRAJAM | CHAYA MARTHANDA
>   SAMBHUTAM TAM NAMAMI SHANAISCHARAM ||
>
> Meaning-  Oh god dressed in blue silk, who has a blue body, Who wears
>   a crown, who sits on vulture, Who gives misfortunes, who is armed with
>   a bow, Who has four hands and who is son of Sun God, Be pleased with
>   me always and happily grant me boons.

**Story Of Piplad Rushi (पिपलाद ऋषि) and Shani Deva :**

Story from Treta Yuga, once there was a terrible famine. **Dadhichi Rushi (दधिची ऋषि)** with his family decided to go to a different place. They all were very hungry. And died because of Hunger. One of the sons of Dadhichi Rushi sat under a Peepal Tree (. पिंपळ , पिपल ,अश्वत्थ ) He started eating peepal leaves and mediate everyday.

One day  Narad Muni going from that area seen him and asked him to chant this mantra - **("Om Namo Bhagvate Vasudevaya  ॐ नमो भगवते वासुदेवाय")**. He started Reciting this mantra.When  Lord Vishnu asked Narad Muni about this  boy , Narada told Lord  Vishnu  about him and his family and all this happened due to **Shani peedha (शनि पीड़ा).** Lord Vishnu blessed him , and he then came to be known as Piplad Rushi .When Rushi Piplad with  his angry eyes looked at shani deva , shani could not face his Teja or power and fell on the ground.Then all the gods came near Piplad and asked him to calm down They also blessed him with a boon that whoever will remember Piplad story during Shani trouble, will get rid of it.
So According to Hindu traditions, to get rid of Shani Grih peedha, Maharshi Piplad is rememberd.

[See Above Story from BLOG](http://gaganmeet.blogspot.in/2009/05/lord-shani-his-famous-stories.html)

**Acoording to Popular belief of Joytisha -**

The impact of Sadesati is supposed to be felt differently by people of different moon signs. It is said that people of Moon sign Aquarius (कुंभ राशि ) do not have any ill effects from Sadesati, while people of Moon sign Leo (सिंह राशि) feel the most impact.

Comment: 1 more question... What should we think about in the story? Should we remember Piplad Rushi or the whole story?

Comment: @AashishKumarShaw - I think we should remember everything. Shani ,The Rushi's story , Various mantras. And most importantly the purpose of Shani and Sade-Sati.

Answer (score -1):

Shani's effects are very dangerous. It is a lazy planet. Definitely it affects career, health etc. If you recite Hanuman chalisa shani will not catch you at all. Shani told hanuman that I should catch you as per the dasa. Hanuman said I am in the work of Lord Rama now. Do not catch me. Shani said I have to. Hanuman replied catch my shoulder. Shani did that. Hanuman flied in the sky very fast. Shani could not bear the speed. He pleaded leave me. Hanuman came to ground. Shani got some energy and said I will catch your feet and did that. Hanuman ran very fast and shani was hit by thorns, stones etc. Again he pleaded leave me.
He at once told hanuman I will not catch you.I will not catch those  who recite your name  with devotion.  This was extracted from Kudumba Jodidam.Hope this clarifies.